# How to weight other factors when using Dijkstra

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm solving this problem where we have a graph, and are trying to get from node 1 to node N. The edge weights are the "cost" and each edge also has a "flow" value. For any path from node 1 to node N, the total cost would be the sum of all the costs of the edges on the path, and the flow would be the minimum flow value among the edges. We want to maximize the ratio of flow/cost.

I had the idea to use Dijkstra to find the smallest cost path from 1 to N, and when I tried finding the path this way I realized I wasn't accounting for flow. I want to perform modified Dijkstra where I take into account the flow of each edge when calculating the best path, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Should I manipulate the edge costs by subtracting or adding extra flow, or would this not work because we are looking at the ratio?

I also tried finding every path through BFS, but there is a time constraint and I am unable to do that as well.

Could anyone give me some tips on how to solve this problem?

Edit:
An example is having 3 nodes, 1, 2, and 3. 1 and 2 have an edge cost of 2, and a flow of 4. 2 and 3 have an edge cost of 5, and a flow of 3. In this example, there is only one path from 1 to N. Its flow is min(3,4)=3 and its cost is 2+5=7. So the ratio would be 3/7. But in most cases we will have several possible paths.

Comment: Since this is a graph flow problem, is the solution necessarily a single path? There could be a cheap way to combine the flows across multiple paths.

Comment: Yes, the problem asks for just a single path.

Comment: Please check your wording! "We want to minimize the ratio of flow/cost." means that it is most preferable to have a high cost!

Comment: An example would help.

Comment: https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/min_cost_flow.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow Dijkstra's algorithm and maintain for each node *v* a distance label D[v] (as usual), and additionally a flow label F[v]. The goal is to maximize the ratio F[v] / D[v]. The vertex *u* the algorithm should select next is the one which maximizes this ratio.

Then, during the relaxation of any incident edge *e=(u,v)*, perform the following computation to see if the ratio of a new possible path from the starting vertex to *v* that uses *u* as an intermediate vertex is better than any previously found path.

```
// relaxing edge e = (u,v)
newDistance = min{ D[u], D[v] + cost(e) }
newFlow = min{ F[u], flow(e) }

if ( (newFlow / newDistance) > (F[v] / D[v]) )
    v.parent = u
    F[v] = newFlow
    D[v] = newDistance
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but you can just use your flow/cost ration as a node weight. It's ok for Dijkstra algorithm.

By the way, I've got a coursework on the same topic, I've got length and speed costs, and using length/speed ratio worked for me. You can see all the sources on [GitHub](https://github.com/artem-bondar/path-finder).

Comment: Since the question is asking for the maximum ratio of flow/cost, would I have to make each edge weight cost/flow, otherwise it will just find the minimum ratio of flow/cost?

Comment: Also, the problem is asking for the maximum ratio of the minimum flow on the path/ total cost. Would this still work?

Comment: For first question I think you should calculate your Djkstar marks in another way, in my case it was updating under `if (pathLength < graph.vertices[neighbours[i]].mark)` condition, for yours it'll be something wiht > condition.

Comment: Didn't understand second question, could you explain what you meant by *maximum ratio of the minimum flow on the path/ total cost*?

Comment: The total cost of the path would the sum of the costs of the edges along the path. The flow rate along the path would be the minimum of the flow values of the edges along the path (since they serves as a bottleneck). We want to maximize the flow rate of the path divided by the cost of the path.

Comment: Oh, finally I've understood your problem. It's completely different from mines. In my case I just minimize total length/speed value. So the question is how to correctly implement Djkstra marks in your case. The problem is that you need to use total cost that is unknown when calculating marks. Need to think about it.